# how to filter json array by some condition

Tags: android

how to filter values from json array i want to filter that if  string  zero1check =0  add only that json array in Category_name.add(object.getString("dish_name")); where  "day":"m1"

if zero1check =0  add in  Category_name.add(object.getString("dish_name")); only that json array which contain "day":"m2"

```
  {
  "status":1,
  "data":
    [
    {
   "school_name":"testing12",
     "menu_title":"Menu1",
    "dish_name":null,
   "day":"m1"
    }
   ,
    {
     "school_name":"testing12"
   ,"menu_title":"Menu1",
      "dish_name":null,
      "day":"m1"
     }

     ,
    {
     "school_name":"testing12"
     ,"menu_title":"Menu1",
  "dish_name":null,
      "day":"m2"
   }


   ,
    {
    "school_name":"testing12"
   ,"menu_title":"Menu1",
   "dish_name":null,
   "day":"m2"
     }
    ]
    }



     static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
 static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
 static ArrayList<String> menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();

         String  zero1check;



            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

            status = json2.getString("status");
            if (status.equals("1")) {



            JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);


                Category_ID.add((long) i);
                Category_name.add(object.getString("dish_name"));




                menu_name.add(object.getString("menu_title"));



                String[] mVal = new String[school.length()];

                for (int k = 0; k < school.length(); k++) {
                    mVal[k] = 
                 school.getJSONObject(k).getString("menu_title");

                    menu_nametxt.setText(mVal[0]);

                }
```

Comment: It is logic, when parsing your json you only need to test the JsonObjects, and JsonArray with some "if"

Comment: help me what do u mean? i want to add  Category_name.add(object.getString("dish_name")); only m1 value if String  zero1check;=0  if  String  zero1check;=1  then add  in
Category_name.add(object.getString("dish_name")); only dish=m2 values from json array

Comment: For now are you able to parse the entire json stream and log it in LogCat?

Comment: what exactly you need ah..if string zero1check =0 means get day m1 dish_name.if string zero1check =1 get day m2 dish_name.correct

Comment: no only string all aray which contain day =m1 or m2

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. then change zero1check datatype as int

```
 JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < school.length(); i1++) {
                        JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i1);

                        if(zero1check == 0)
                        {

                            if(object.getString("id").equals("m1"))
                            {
                                Category_name.add(object.getString("dish_name"));
                            }

                        }
                        else if(zero1check == 1)
                        {

                            if(object.getString("id").equals("m2"))
                            {
                                Category_name.add(object.getString("dish_name"));
                            }

                        }

                    }
```